# How do I delete a Google Plus Huddle message?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, google-plus-huddles

I shared a message in Google Plus Huddle with one of my contact.  I am looking for a way to delete the message but cannot find anything.  I even cleared my Google Plus data from Manage Apps but the message comes back after signing back in.

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete a Google Plus Huddle message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like there a way to delete Huddles, only hide them.  Navigate to the message, hit the menu button on the handset, and select "Hide".